# Google weather api, issue reading xml

Tags: java, xml, scala, urlconnection

I'm using scala to read an xml from google's weather api:

```
val response = new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=MyCity").openStream()
var respXML = response.read()
println(respXML)
```

but when i run it the `println` prints a number: `60` instead of the actual xml, i already tried it with the `curl` utility and it worked fine, forgive my ignorance but im new to java's net classes and as far as i know from the tutorials this should work.

This is all the relevant code, there isn't much more than this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Scala, scala.io.Source is your good friend.

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.xml.XML
import java.net.URL

val source = Source.fromURL(new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=MyCity"))
val xmlString = source.mkString  // Raw XML String
val xml = XML.loadString(xmlString)  // Scala XML object
```

Comment: It works, i guess i will never know what happened in the java version, i'll check for more on the scala.io package

Comment: @user1108631 The problem of your Java version is that when you call read() on an InputStream, it only read ONE byte from the stream and return it as an int, not the whole content as String. And because the very first character(byte) in the response XML is '<', which is 60 if you convert it to integer. That why you get 60 instead of the actual XML.